# Extracting fields from a long string using excel and stripping out slashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to strip out values from samples of data.

Looking at the example below.

```
/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/rg-1234/providers/microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups/nsg-1234
```

I would like to strip out the following into specific columns

- The section labelled as `XXXXX`
- The section labelled as `rg-1234`
- The last section section after which there will be no more slashes
  labelled as `nsg-1234`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula.

```
=LET(s,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),
     CHOOSECOLS(s,3,5,COLUMNS(s)))
```

It splits the string and then takes the specified columns.

[image]

Comment: I get an error `#SPILL!` i am guessing its not office 365

Comment: Spill is usually because the cells next to it is occupied by other data. Make sure the cells to the right of the cell you put the formula in is empty

Comment: Work now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

While Ike's solution is perfectly fine.

I'd use `=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),2,4,-1)` where `-1` means first from the right (last position) of the array result.

If you would want to spill the result for multiple cells at once, you'll find textsplit alone no longer spills to the right, but returns only the first spill result.
This formula is a workaround: `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A2,"/",{2,4,-1}),"/")`

Comment: And what a workaround it is! Great!

Comment: @VBasic2008 If the cell did not start with the delimiter we needed to add it in front like: `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("/"&A1:A2,"/",{2,4,-1}),"/")` nice to know for different use cases.

Comment: Here's a somewhat flexible Lambda function: `=LAMBDA(data,split_cols,delimiter,[scan_by_cols],[if_error],LET(sbc,IF(ISOMITTED(scan_by_cols),0,scan_by_cols),ife,IF(ISOMITTED(if_error),"",if_error),IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(TOCOL(data,,sbc),delimiter,TOROW(split_cols)),delimiter),ife)))` that I utilized with `=SplitToRows(A1:B10,{2;4;-1},"/")`.